# Horse betting game

Tags: probability

3 horse, racing, you could buy ticket 1 dollar to bet on each horse win. For every dollar you bet, the profit you could win from the three are 2, 4, and 6 dollars, how do you play this game?

I am thinking about let the money bet on each horse be x, y, z. And then for each scenario I would try to get the same profit:

2x - y - z = 4y - x - z = 6z - x - y

Is this the correct way to think about this? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Actually I found a link that talks about the exact same problem https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/8jr7lw/help_probability_interview_question_on_betting_on/, but still I don't understand it.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer: you need to know, or assume, the chances of each horse winning.

Comment: let's say if the chances are equal?

Comment: The Reddit link has the question being to find a betting strategy that guarantees making money. Is that what you're asking for here?

Comment: If that is the goal, would 2x - y - z > 0, 4y - x - z > 0, 6z - x - y > 0 suffice?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Are 2, 4, and 6 the return or the profits? E.g. if 2 is the profit and 1 is what you had been betting, then you get 3 back.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether this is a [Dutch book](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book).

For this you need a sum the reciprocals of returns (which is the amount that you would have to bet to get 1 return) and see if the total is above 1.

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{11}{12} < 1$$

So this is a Dutch book and you have a garanteed profit.